# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "value" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1

Tags: tensorflow, reshape, tensor, dimension

I'm new to tensorflow.When I try to modify the model structure, I transform a tensor 'r',whose shape is (None,1) into a one-dimensional tensor with tf.reshape(r,[4,]), and then input it into the dense layer. The shape of the one-dimensional tensor is (4,), and The input_shape of the dense layer is set to (4,), and an error occurs.
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "value" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (4,)
I will appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem
my tensorflow version is 2.10.0

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the data as `(samples or batch, data shape)`. So, the input data has at least 2 dimensions.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32))
x=tf.random.normal((4,))
y=tf.random.uniform((4,),0,1)
model.compile('rmsprop','binary_crossentropy',)
model.fit(x,y)
```

The above code raises the following value error

```
Input 0 of layer "dense_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
```

After changing the input shape to (batch, data shape) the model works fine.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32))
# The input data should be of shape (batch_size, data shape)
x=tf.random.normal((120,4,))
y=tf.random.uniform((120,),0,1)
model.compile('rmsprop','binary_crossentropy',)
model.fit(x,y)
```

Output:

```
4/4 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 4.2611
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fa2e901db90>
```